# Violates content security policy directive: img-src * 'self' data: https:"

Tags: html, vue.js, content-security-policy

I'm trying to get `dynamic` image from my server and I got these `errors`.
First I was getting

`Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". 
Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.`

My content was:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;  'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">
```

Then I searched on stackoverflow and changed my content to:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *;
   img-src * 'self' data: https:; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
   style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">
```

`violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src * 'self' data: https:".`

Comment: What is the markup for your image?  
`img-src * data:` *should* allow any image...

Answer (score 1):

I got that fixed by commenting out that line. That might work for you as well.

Comment: Which line? Please elaborate to make your answer useful

Comment: I don't think it to be secure way but commenting out the line that is in index.html

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">` helps.